# Time Parsing Library Similar to JIRA Time Format

Tags: java, scala

I'm looking for a parsing library for strings of the format `"2y 1M 3w 4d 12h 20m 10s"` (2 years, 1 month, 3 weeks, 4 days, 12 hours, 20 minutes, and 10 seconds). Parsing them into Millis would likely be the shortest path forward. Essentially, I am looking to add/subtract the parsed string from a timestamp.

Comment: http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/PeriodFormatterBuilder.html

Comment: Looks like that will fit the bill - thanks for linking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution courtesy @shmosel:

```
import org.joda.time.format.PeriodFormatterBuilder

val pf = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
      .appendYears()
      .appendSuffix(" y", "y")
      .appendSeparator("", " ")
      .appendMonths()
      .appendSuffix(" M", "M")
      .appendSeparator("", " ")
      .appendWeeks()
      .appendSuffix(" w", "w")
      .appendSeparator("", " ")
      .appendDays()
      .appendSuffix(" d", "d")
      .appendSeparator("", " ")
      .appendHours()
      .appendSuffix(" h", "h")
      .appendSeparator("", " ")
      .appendMinutes()
      .appendSuffix(" m", "m")
      .appendSeparator("", " ")
      .appendSeconds()
      .appendSuffix(" s", "s")
      .toFormatter()

    // Is there a more idiomatic way to add
    val buffer = pf.parsePeriod(bufferPeriod)
```

Note that order matters (`10y 10s` is valid, `10s 10y` is not).